# Как передать в переменную Django models ввод телефона с клавиатуры реализованную на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, django-model

Есть форма обратной связи, необходимо передать ввод номера телефона с клавиатуры реализованную на `JavaScript` в переменную `phone` файла `models.py`:

```
class FeedbackModel(models.Model):
    # Класс модели обратной связи
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя')
    phone = ''
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField(max_length=5000, verbose_name='Сообщение')
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.email}'
```

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from .models import FeedbackModel
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField


class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
    class Meta:
        model = FeedbackModel
        exclude = ['create_at']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите имя'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите email'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'phone'}),
            'message': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите сообщение'})
        }
```

Ниже кусок кода `html`

```
<div class="contact__form">                     
    <div class="contact__form__title">
      <h2>СВЯЗАТЬСЯ</h2>
      <p>Здесь Вы можете задать интересующие Вас вопросы.</p>
    </div>
    <form action="{% url 'feedback' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Имя: {{ form.name }}
        Телефон: <input type="tel" data-tel-input placeholder="Введите номер телефона" maxlength="18" />
        Email: {{ form.email }}           
        Сообщение: {{ form.message }}
        Captcha*: {{ form.captcha }}
        <button type="submit" class="site-btn">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Добавляю `views.py`:

```
class FeedbackView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        contacts = ContactLink.objects.all()
        form = FeedbackForm()
        return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', {'contacts': contacts, 'form': form})


class CreateFeedback(CreateView):
    form_class = FeedbackForm
    success_url = '/'
```

Comment: Тэгу input добавить атрибут name="имя_атрибута", и на вьюхе забрать содержимое request.POST.get('имя_атрибута').

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar там же уже есть type="tel" разве я его не могу использовать? Более того я уже пробовал так сделать, но у меня ничего не получилось. Как мне забрать содержимое `request.POST.get("tel")` и поместить в переменную **phone в** `models.py` Сейчас файл `views.py` добавлю

Comment: Для начала определить метод post. У Вас во вьюхе определен только get метод, далее нужно разобрать request (request.POST.get('имя_атрибута')). В Вашей форме (в шаблоне в тэге <form>) указан метод POST, все что присутствует в форме (поля, кнопки и т.д.) прилетит во вьюху в виде словаря где будут использоваться только name тэга и value тэга (если  атрибут value предусмотрен), атрибут type во вьюху не придет, он используется только HTML разметкой.

Comment: И учитывая тот факт что у Вас используется самодельное поле для ввода телефона не факт что данные из этого поля пройдут валидацию в джанго (но это не точно).

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar пиши ответ, приму. У меня получилось вернуть номер телефона по type="tel"

Comment: Через переопределение метода post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во вьюхе нужно разобрать request.POST и получить из него необходимое поле

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]